# function that converts any number into time format in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, variables, logical-operators

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a number and converts it into hours and minutes. The problem is that that code is not printing 0 as singular for example "0 minute" not "0 minutes" same for hours. here is my code:

```js
function convertNumToTime(num) {
  var hour = Math.floor(num / 60);
  var minutes = (num % 60);

  var hourText;
  if (hour <= 1) {
    hourText = "hour";
  } else {
    hourText = "hours";
  }
  var minuteText;
  if (minutes <= 1) {
    minuteText = "minute";
  } else {
    minuteText = "minutes";
  }

  console.log(hour + " " + hourText + ", " + minutes + " " + minuteText);
}

convertNumToTime(176)
convertNumToTime(0)
```

Comment: _"that code is not printing 0 as singular for example"_ - It does... So what's the actual problem/question?

Comment: `var hourText = \`hour${hour === 1 ? ''  : 's'}\`;
  var minuteText = \`minute${minutes === 1 ? '' : 's'}\`;`

Comment: ONLY `1` is singular! [Rules](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7817/singular-or-plural-for-seconds/7825#7825)

Comment: @mplungjan So instead of just to replace `<=` with `==` OP should stuff the `if...else...` into a single line because...?

Comment: @Andreas DRY :)

Comment: @mplungjan What happened to your _"... rules"_ comment? Not relevant anymore? And DRY because of two times `minute` and `hour`...?

Comment: Rules still there

Answer (score 0):

A tiny local `pluralize` helper function implements the rule of whether to concat `"s"` to a provided text just once.

The clumsy `if...else` handling then can be skipped, and one can write a more readable code for aggregating the final result ...

```js
function minutesToHoursAndMinutesText(value) {
  const pluralize = (num, text) =>
    (num === 1) ? text : `${ text }s`;
    // (num === 1) ? text : [text, 's'].join('');

  value = parseFloat(value);

  const hours = Math.floor(value / 60);
  const minutes = Math.round(value % 60);

return [
    `${ hours } ${ pluralize(hours, 'hour') }`,
    `${ minutes } ${ pluralize(minutes, 'minute') }`,
  ].join(', ');
}

console.log(
  'minutesToHoursAndMinutesText(176) ...',
  minutesToHoursAndMinutesText(176)
);
console.log(
  'minutesToHoursAndMinutesText(0) ...',
  minutesToHoursAndMinutesText(0)
);

console.log(
  'minutesToHoursAndMinutesText(61) ...',
  minutesToHoursAndMinutesText(61)
);
console.log(
  'minutesToHoursAndMinutesText("64.567905") ...',
  minutesToHoursAndMinutesText("64.567905")
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `[text, 's'].join('')` is more understandable as `\`${text}s\`` in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still a beginner in programming and this surely will help.

Comment: @Billions_Mero ... in case this answer was helpful maybe consider flagging this A. as the accepted one; there is a button for it.